# how to slowly change the skybox color in unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to change the color or tint of my skybox so it will slowl turn to black. I have looked for a while now and I still cant find anything on this. Here is my code right now:

```
public class SkyboxColorChanger : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Color colorStart = Color.blue;
    public Color colorEnd = Color.red;
    public float duration = 1.0F;

    private void Update () 
    {
        float lerp = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, duration) / duration;
        RenderSettings.skybox.SetColor("_Tint", Color.Lerp(colorStart, colorEnd, lerp));
    }
}
```

The problems with this one are:

1. in the options it appears this would only work if the sky was a solid color.
2. when I did get it to work it changed at a very fast rate (im looking for a very long time between the changes).

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Please don't include empty methods

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public float step = 0;

private void Update ()
{
    RenderSettings.skybox.SetColor("_Tint", Color.Lerp(colorStart, colorEnd, step));
    step += Time.deltaTime / duration;
}
```